# Drupal ApacheSolr Query to filter on the language of the content

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to ApacheSolr Search. I'm trying to modify the ApacheSolrQuery to filter on the language of the content. I first modified the search form:

```
function myips_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if($form_id=='apachesolr_search_custom_page_search_form'){

     $form['languages_options'] = array(
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => array('ar' => t('Arabic'),
                            'en' => t('English'),
                            'und' => t('Neutral'))
     );
     $form['type'] = array(
       '#title' => t('Language'),
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#description' => "Select the Language of the content",
       '#options' => $form['languages_options']['#value'],
     );
     }
}
```

My ApacheSolr admin page show that the ss_language field is already indexed by default (So I think I don't need to add it to the index) . I know need to pass the parameter of the languages options and alter my ApacheSolr. I have read about form_apachesolr_query_alter($query) but I don't understand how to use it, and what exactly is the difference between "addFilter" and "addParam" and how to pass the selected language option in the form to the query. Could you please further explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

use [search_api_solr](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module. By using this you can create view exposed form for searching, you can use all node fields(language,nid,title etc..) in exposed filter and don't need to write any form alter code.